# How to disable vibration when typing on HTC One X?

Tags: htc-one-x, vibration, softkey

I have HTC One X. Each time I'm texting on WhatsApp, it's always vibrating. Since it's using too much battery and it's really annoying, I want to disable it.

Under "Settings", there's no "Sound" setting or "Language and Keyboard", there is only "Language & Input".

How do I disable vibration when typing?

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Settings > Language & keyboard > HTC Sense Input` and turn off the option of `Vibration feedback`. It is present in both HTC Sense 4 and 5. It is even described in this [YouTube video](http://youtu.be/h039_HuwbMY).